# How get model from modelmetadata?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 4 and 5 model metadata has property "Model"

In MVC 6 (ASP.Net core mvc), this property is gone.

So now, how do I get "Model" from model metadata?

Comment: improved readability. Fixed spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution.

ViewData has ModelExplorer, where can find property by modelmetadata.

```
ViewData.ModelExplorer.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => Equals(x.Metadata, metadata)).Model
```